# how to use short code in a <?php ?> tag in .php file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using "Profile Builder" plugin to show registration form on my site in wordpress.
It works when I add it in the text file in this format [wppb-register].   But I want it inside if else condition, if the user is logged in do not show this form otherwise display it???
How can I implement it.
[wppb-register] is the short code.

Comment: use <?php echo do_shortcode('wppb-register'); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[wppb-register]` like this -

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()){
     echo "You are logged In";
     }else{
     echo do_shortcode('[wppb-register]');
     }
?>
```

This code use to create a new page called Register (or something similar) we can use the [wppb-register] shortcode.

> Read More Information about shortcode -
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/
>   https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/shortcodes/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one help:

```
   if (! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo do_shortcode('wppb-register'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wppb-register]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/
some thing like this:

```
    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()){
         // do some thing
         }else{
         echo do_shortcode('[wppb-register]');
         }
    ?>
```